# The instance of entity type 'WorkStreamOption' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

When I am using repository pattern . I got error

> The instance of entity type 'WorkStreamOption' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values."

I am using ICollection.

```
public class workstream
{
    public ICollection<WorkStreamWorkItem> WorkStreamWorkItem => _workStreamWorkItem;
    private readonly List<WorkStreamWorkItem> _workStreamWorkItem = new List<WorkStreamWorkItem>();
}

public class workItem
{
    public ICollection<WorkStreamOption> WorkStreamOption => _workStreamOption;
    private readonly List<WorkStreamOption> _workStreamOption = new List<WorkStreamOption>();
}
```

I want to create a relationship from workstream to workitem and workstreamoption to workitem .

I have added Table structure something that I attached . I have multiple workitem with one optionid which is attached with one workstream .
When I am adding one data with relate to optionid with workitem and workstream and then when I am adding another data then it throws error .
Anyone can help to sort out my issue .Please paste here .

update data when one optiongroupid having multiple workitems .

Comment: You should show the code that throws the exception and also the full classes that are involved. We only see two navigation properties. They're not inherently throwing this exception.